# RestSharp converts Datetimes to UTC

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have following problem

I'm using RestSharp for accessing my API. But when I'm sending a DateTime it seems to be converted to UTC.
I'm sending '10.06.1991 00:00' and the API gets '09.06.1991 22:00'

So, I would always need to add 2 hours when my API gets a DateTime-object?

I checked the JSON RestSharp sends to the API.

```
public class Test
{
    public int IntProperty {get;set;}
    public string StringProperty {get;set;}
    public DateTime DateTimeProperty {get;set;}
}
```

My object is

```
Test t = new Test{ IntProperty=3, StringProperty="string", DateTimeProperty=new DateTime(1991,06,10) }
```

when I'm sending the object via RestSharp, the JSON my API receives is

```
{
    "IntProperty":3,
    "StringProperty":"string",
    "DateTimeProperty":"09.06.1991 22:00:00"
}
```

Any idea what I could do?
Thanks

Comment: Is that the same issue as https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/691 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not your API that receives wrong data, it's your client that sends "wrong" data. I got the same problem with my API. 
No, it's correct data but converted to UTC.

The exact problem is described here: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/834

So, don't add 2 hours to each DateTime you get it in your API. You would perhaps change correct data when another client sends unconverted dates.

1. You could check, whether on GET you receive the right date. Maybe RestSharp is converting that "wrong" datetime back to `10.06.1991 00:00` - maybe you are okay with it
2. if you want the database to not contain UTC but the data you original wanted to send, don't use the default serializer, use JSON.Net (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). It won't convert to UTC and sends the original DateTime.

Here is one really good example on how to implement: http://bytefish.de/blog/restsharp_custom_json_serializer/

- you write a custom class that implements `ISerializer` and `IDeserializer`
- in serialize you call JSON.Net `Serialize` while in deserialize you call JSON.Net `Deserialize`
- you just need to add a handler to your RestClient like this: (I'm using the static Default-instance described in the mentioned blog)

my client looks like:

```
private readonly RestClient _client;

public RestApiClient(string apiAdress)
{
    _client = new RestClient(apiAdress);
    _client.AddHandler("application/json", () => NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Default);
}
```

and in requests you can set the `JsonSerializer`:

```
 IRestRequest restRequest = 
        new RestRequest(request.GetRestfulUrl(), request.Method) {
            RequestFormat = request.DataFormat, 
            JsonSerializer = NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Default 
        };
```

Comment: what variable is `request`?

Comment: It's just an object containing the path and other information to request the API. Nothing special. Important is just to set the `JsonSerializer` to the the one using Json.Net.

Comment: This helped me, although the AddHandler you specified is now obselete, change to be `_client.AddHandler("application/json", () => NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Default);`

Comment: The problem for me was that date with unspecified kind in json `2022-01-02 23:00` was set to DateTime.Kind = `UTZ` instead of `Unspecified`.
The above solution is no longer available (NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Default), but found that now you can add nuget RestSharp.Serializers.NewtonsoftJson and set the handler with:
`client.UseNewtonsoftJson();`
Now the unspecified dates remains unspecified. :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's because your `DateTime` objects have `DateTime.Kind` property equals to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` - it breaks all conversions between local and utc kinds. I mean some tool assumes that your DateTime is in Utc when it isn't really.

So just don't fight with the tools which have to guess the right kind of your DateTimes in the middle between you and your client. Just use UTC everywhere and convert to local only to show it to user.

Or, even better, use [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) which is more suitable to deal with multizone times.. or even use Jon Skeet's [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) library which is a swiss knife for any time-related work (although, maybe it's an overkill for your case).

**UPD**. To answer the question from @Matthias Burger in comments below:

> How would you work with dates like date of birth? I think "10.06.1991" could be a birthday. Means, in UTC his birthday were different than GMT - wouldn't it?

As always - it depends :)

As time is a tricky thing, you should be careful - and there is a great article from the Jon Skeet's blog about [joys of date/time arithmetic](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/01/the-joys-of-date-time-arithmetic/). I know it's not a real answer, honestly, but there're too much different possible problem cases - do we need to compare dates, are they in the same calendar, do we assume that all people were born at midnight in local time zone and etc.

In already mentioned `NodaTime` there's a concept of global and local instants (look at it's [concepts page](http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/userguide/concepts)). I think for the most simple cases when we need to just store and show birthdays `LocalDate` (local date instant) is enough. Even `DateTime` is enough if you store local date and fixate the same time zone for all (so it'll be like you don't use time zone at all).

P.S. Btw, don't know if the last question was a check or not, but [UTC is a standard and GMT is a time zone](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html) ;)

Comment: Only for my interrest and better understanding: How would you work with dates like date of birth? I think "10.06.1991" could be a birthday. Means, in UTC his birthday were different than GMT - wouldn't it?